# Recommended order for the Larry Niven "of Worlds" books?

Tags: suggested-order, larry-niven, known-space

I just finished [Larry Niven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Niven)'s [*Destroyer of Worlds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destroyer_of_Worlds_%28novel%29) then picked up [*Betrayer of Worlds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betrayer_of_Worlds) and [*Fleet of Worlds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleet_of_Worlds) at the library. A quick check of the dust jacket synopsis doesn't clue me in as to which order I should read them in, and since they are both prequels to [*Ringworld*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld), I'm not sure the publishing date is a sure indicator of the story's timeline. What order should I read them in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order of publication for the Ringworld prequels:

1. Fleet of Worlds (2007)
2. Juggler of Worlds (2008)
3. Destroyer of Worlds (2009)
4. Betrayer of Worlds (2010)
5. Fate of Worlds (2012)

Although the books may be enjoyed singly, they do have overlapping plots, characters, and locations - and a sense of continuity that probably makes the most sense in the above order.

Comment: Awesome. I would have missed "Juggler". Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Enjoy!

Comment: *Fate of Worlds* is to be released around summer 2012. From the description on Amazon and the cover, it's a sequel to both the "Fleet of Worlds" *and* the "Ringworld" series.