# Advise on Ringworld series

Tags: suggested-order, known-space, ringworld

I just got finished reading the "Ringworld" series by Larry Niven (*Ringworld*, *The Ringworld Engineers*, *The Ringworld Throne*, *Ringworld's Children*). Should I now read the "Fleet of Worlds" series (*Fleet of Worlds*, *Juggler of Worlds*, *Destroyer of Worlds*, *Betrayer of Worlds*) and then read "Fate of Worlds" as I've heard that it's a conclusion to both the Ringworld series and the Fleet of Worlds series. I'm new to the Known universe as you can tell.

Comment: I don't know why this is attracting so many close votes.  It's just a suggested reading order question, which is nothing new on this site.  Known Space is a sprawling epic at this point containing dozens of novels, novellas and short stories.  Asking for some help navigating through this material seems reasonable.

Comment: Related: [Recommended order for the Larry Niven “of Worlds” books?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15465/2242)

Answer (score 4):

Read the novel *Protector* first, if you haven't read it already.  It contains backstory that is quite pertinent to the Ringworld books.  Also, the story in *Protector* is directly continued and resolved in the *Destroyer/Betrayer/Fate of Worlds* trio of books.

Read the Niven short stories "Borderland of Sol", "Neutron Star", "At the Core", and "Procrustes" before tackling *Fleet of Worlds* and *Juggler of Worlds* as those novels are partial retellings of the short stories and surrounding events, but from different points of view.

Note that the *... of Worlds* books are neck deep in Puppeteer culture and politics.  If your interest is primarily about the Pak, stay away except for *Destroyer of Worlds*, in which the Pak drive the plot from beginning to end.